# Run ReactJS application which using webpack and babel without server and by opening HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, server

I couldn't find the proper answer for my problem so if there is any same question please let me know.
I'm new in ReactJs and I was wondering if anyone could help me.
I have the react project which is using Webpack to bundle components. It works fine with npm start on port 3000 but I need to run it without the server and I want to see it by opening the HTML file. The App just calls APIs in its components so it doesn't need the server.
I have the same project and it works well but because it uses Webpack as well it's hard to find out what is missing in my project.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate an html file you can run npm run build that will generate all your static files in the build directory including a static html.

However i think you would still need a server to make async calls.